# Getting the OpenID URL from a Grails Controller/Service

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-security

I'm using acegi 0.5.2 and enabled OpenID support. I would like to know how to accesss the URL (or username) returned by a provider (i.e. Google, Yahoo!). I can't find any docs about that so I traced the code of acegi and found this in GrailsOpenIdAuthenticationProvider:

```
OpenIDAuthenticationToken response = (OpenIDAuthenticationToken) authentication
OpenIDAuthenticationStatus status = response.status

// handle the various possibilites
if (status == OpenIDAuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS) {
 // Lookup user details
 UserDetails userDetails = _userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(response.identityUrl)
 return new GrailsOpenIdAuthenticationToken(userDetails, response.status, response.identityUrl)
}
```

it seems that the response.identityUrl contains what i need. How can get it from a controller's (or service's) space?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a very long research and doing several trial and errors, i've found the solution.

acegi plugin provides a LoginController for your project and it has this action: authfail. inside its implementation, you can check the OpenID value thru this code:

```
println "openid = ${session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION'].extraInformation}"
```

with that, you can then automatically create a new User record or do anything you want with the OpenID given by a provider.